# How to get DropdownMenuItem from a list

Tags: flutter

I have tried to use a function and for in loop to loop through a list and then create dropdownMenuItems. I am getting this error 'There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value'. I have look through similar solutions stating that the default value should be one of the values of the list which is not my case
Below is the list

```
const List<String> currenciesList = [
  'AUD',
  'BRL',
  'CAD',
  'CNY',
  'EUR',
  'GBP',
  'HKD',
  'IDR',
  'ILS',
  'INR',
  'JPY',
  'MXN',
  'NOK',
  'NZD',
  'PLN',
  'RON',
  'RUB',
  'SEK',
  'SGD',
  'USD',
  'ZAR'
];
```

and the loop

```
String selectedCurrency = 'USD';
  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> dropdownItems = [];
  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> getDropDownItems() {
    for (String currency in currenciesList) {
      var newItem = DropdownMenuItem(
        child: Text(currency),
        value: currency,
      );
      dropdownItems.add(newItem);
    }
    return dropdownItems;
  }
```

lastly the dropdownbutton

```
child: DropdownButton<String>(
              value: selectedCurrency,
              items: getDropDownItems(),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedCurrency = value!;
                });
              },
```

Please help me understand what i must have done wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code-snippet

```dart
 DropdownButton<String>(
              value: selectedCurrency,
              items: getDropDownItems(), ///<= adding items on every state-build  
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedCurrency = value!;
                });
              },
```

On state changes means after you click on `DropdownMenuItem` you are calling again `getDropDownItems(),` in this case our it will add `DropdownMenuItem` again to `dropdownItems`, and so the `DropdownButton` having duplicate values, and you are getting errors.

Use `initState` to call it once, or just initialize the dropdownMenuItem.

**Here is the Solution Widget**

```dart
class _ItemSectionState extends State<ItemSection> {
  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> dropdownItems = []; //* you can make nullable if you want, I'm doing it to force having String. 

  String selectedCurrency = 'USD';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    dropdownItems = List.generate(
      currenciesList.length,
      (index) => DropdownMenuItem(
        value: currenciesList[index],
        child: Text(
          currenciesList[index],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          DropdownButton<String>(
            items: dropdownItems,
            value: selectedCurrency,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                selectedCurrency = value!;
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs due to duplicate values..

When you try to change the value of the drop down, the `getDropDownItems` function is rerun and the logic in there just duplicates the values for the dropdown.

a quick fix would be to simply `map` over the `currenciesList` as opposed to writing a function to add the widgets to a List as shown below:

---

```dart
  String selectedCurrency = 'USD';

...

child: DropdownButton<String>(
        value: selectedCurrency,
        items: currenciesList.map((currency) => DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Text(currency),
          value: currency,
         ),
        ),
       onChanged: (value) {
         setState(() {
           selectedCurrency = value!;
         });
         },

...
```